# Recursively creating tables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I just started to create something that creates a table with x rows and you can put however many columns in a row that you want. Whenever I attempt to run it, it only creates one cell. How do I fix this?

```js
var xio = parseInt(prompt("How many weighted areas are in this subject?"))

for (i = 5; xio > 0; xio--) {


  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";

  var firstRow = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[xio];
  var x = firstRow.insertCell(0);
  x.innerHTML = "New cell";


}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Comment: Open your console, it's telling you why :)

Comment: @JeremyThille I can't, I'm on a school laptop that has inspect element/console blocked. Can you please tell me? Edit: Nevermind, thanks stackoverflow code snippet thing!

Comment: A school laptop that prevents using developer tools? What kind of school is that? The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertCell' of undefined`

Comment: code is not looping to create multiple cells.... It should have two loops

Comment: @JeremyThille It's odd. First they tell us that we're allowed to and supposed to learn basic computer science, which they give us resources like Scratch to use, while the more experienced people can't. It's quite unfortunate, and I'm fairly certain that the high school does that as well :(.

Comment: loop create row { loop create cells for row } }

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Two for loops.... Doing it would be doing your homework.... Outside loop, you create a new table row, inside loop, you create a cell and append it to that row.

Comment: "something that creates a table with x rows and you can put however many columns in a row that you want": so the prompted value is what, the number of rows or the number of columns?

Comment: @JeremyThille concerning your last answer I understand how to create the rows correctly, but how do you make more than one collumn?

Comment: @squills you need to get the number of cells from the user first see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55421452/2813224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no prompt for second input so even if the rest of your code was ok (which it isn't) there'd be only one cell. As far as the cells/columns you need to create them in a loop within the loop that creates the rows. Note how the loops syntax is in demo.

```js
var rQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Rows"), 10);
var cQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Columns"), 10);
var table = document.getElementById("xTable");

for (let i = 0; i < rQty; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  for (let j = 0; j < cQty; j++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = "NEW CELL";
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px ridge #333;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="xTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create table by using the below function

```
function makeTableHTML(myArray)
 { 
    var result = "<table border=1>"; 
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
     result += "<tr>"; 
    for(var j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++){ 
    result += "<td>"+myArray[i][j]+"</td>";
     } 
    result += "</tr>";
     } 
    result += "</table>"; 
    return result; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to select `table.rows[xio]` but if `xio === 5`, the row number 5 doesn't exist yet (because it's iteration 1), so it crashes.

Do it the other way around. Instead of looping by decreasing xio, loop by increasing i.

```js
var xio = parseInt(prompt("How many weighted areas are in this subject?")),
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");

for (i = 0; i < xio; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(0),
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Rows"), 10);
var cQty = parseInt(prompt("Number of Columns"), 10);
var table = document.getElementById("xTable");

for (let i = 0; i < rQty; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  for (let j = 0; j < cQty; j++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = "NEW CELL";
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px ridge #333;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="xTable"></table>
```

Comment: @zer00ne what language is that in? I tried to run that with js/html/css, and for some reason it's not working...

Comment: It's in JavaScript. You are not getting a table on this site or....? I'm getting perfect results from both demos. BTW you should delete this post since it's the same as my answer. The mods will get irritated.

Comment: @zer00ne My bad! I put the table tags behind the script. I will delete it too. Thank you for your help! EDIT: It won't let me delete it, sorry.

Comment: No worries. The best place to place script tags are right before the closing `</body>` tag.